# Is there any way to store responses in parse server sdk flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform

I am using `parse_server_sdk_flutter` library. To save data in cache I manually save them to sharedpreferences. Is there any way to store responses automatically?

```dart
final query = QueryBuilder(ParseObject('Clubs'));

final response = await query.query();

if (response.success) {
      final results = response.results;
}
```

I have tried to fetch using this query, then reopen the app without the internet.